# using twill to follow link id

Tags: twill

I have this simple twill code

```
>>> from twill.commands import *
>>> go("http://stackoverflow.com:80")
==> at http://stackoverflow.com:80
'http://stackoverflow.com:80'
>>> showlinks()
1. log in ==> /users/login
2. careers ==> http://careers.stackoverflow.com
3. chat ==> http://chat.stackoverflow.com
4. meta ==> http://meta.stackoverflow.com
5. about ==> /about
```

I know I can do

```
>>> follow('careers')
 ==> at http://careers.stackoverflow.com
'http://careers.stackoverflow.com'
>>>
```

but how do i specify the link number, for example,

```
>>> follow(2)
```

does not work?

The reason is that I want to test a website which has many links and I want to build the list of the links I want to follow.

How would one do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

twill's `follow` function expects a string as an argument. try something like the following:

`>>> follow('2')`
or
`>>> follow(str(2))`